# Is it possible to not load associations after insertion with ExMachina?

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

I'm using [ex_machina](https://github.com/thoughtbot/ex_machina) to create fixture for my unit-tests.

I'm saving some records to the database using ExMachina `insert(:comment)` but my assertions are wrong because ExMachina always load relations and it's not the case when I'm fetching with Ecto and not calling `Repo.preload`.

Let's say I have 2 factories `comment` and `user`:

```
def user_factory do
  %User{
    name: "some name"
  }
end

def comment_factory do
  %Comment{
    content: "some content",
    user: build(:user)
  }
end
```

when I'm testing

```
  test "should retrieve last comment" do
    comment = fixture(:comment)
    assert Comment.get_last_comment() == comment
  end
```

Assertion if failing because on the left I have

```
%Comment{
    ...,
    content: "some content",
    user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>
}
```

and on the right

```
%Comment{
    ...,
    content: "some content",
    user: %User{ name: "some name" }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid:

- using `Repo.preload` on my left records because sometimes there are quite a lot of dependencies
- testing each property individually

Thanks by advance for your help

Comment: `assert Comment.get_last_comment().content == comment.content`?

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa but I'm trying to avoid testing each property independently

Comment: Then you probably might want to take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49997873/2035262

Comment: Finally I followed the approach you referenced. If you create an answer I'll accept it @mudasobwa

Comment: If you followed the approach I referenced, I believe the proper way to handle this would be to mark this question as a duplicate of the referenced one and +1 the answer there.

Answer (score 2):

I've tackled this problem by defining a `equal_records` function in `test/support/data_case.ex` that just compares the type of the structs and the ids of the records:

```
def equal_records(%{__struct__: t1, id: id1}, %{__struct__: t2, id: id2}) do
  t1 == t2 and id1 == id2
end

def equal_records(_, _), do: false
```

Usage:

```
test "should retrieve last comment" do
  comment = fixture(:comment)
  assert equal_records(Comment.get_last_comment(), comment)
end
```

To also test lists of records, add these functions too:

```
def equal_records([], []), do: true
def equal_records([h1 | t1], [h2 | t2]) do
  equal_records(h1, h2) and equal_records(t1, t2)
end
```

Comment: That's an approach but I prefer the one suggested here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49997873/2035262 by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035262/mudasobwa